# Rounding number up or down, based on 0.5 and closest to round number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble using **CEILING and FLOOR in SQL Server**.

> The problem is, I want to round up based on decimal value 0.5

**For example:**

```
- 2.56 -> 3
- 1.2 -> 1
- 4.1 -> 4
- 0.7 -> 1
- 0.48 -> 0
```

As you can see, I need to get lower round number if decimal value is < .5 and higher round number if >= .5.

CEILING and FLOOR only round up to lowest or highest decimal value and I do not get the desired results.

> Any suggestions?

Comment: [ROUND (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 2):

I would expect `round()` to do what you want.  But if you want to be explicit, then try:

```
floor(x + 0.5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Read this ...https://sqlstudies.com/2016/10/05/floor-round-and-ceiling/

**Round** does a standard rounding. If value is .5 or over then you get back 1. If it’s less than .5 you get back 0

**Ceiling** returns the integer equal to or higher than the value passed in.

```
    SELECT ROUND(2.56,0); 
    Answer= 3.00

    SELECT ROUND(2.56,1); 
    Answer= 2.60

    SELECT CEILING(2.56);
    Answer= 3
```

Comment: What about .5 ? Example: using ROUND() on 10.5 gives me = 10. Shouldn't it round to 11 ?

Comment: SELECT ROUND(10.5, 0) --Answer 11.0 to it will calculate Ones place.....

SELECT ROUND(10.5, 1) --Answer 10.5 to it will calculate Tens place.....

Answer (score 1):

In case if you have requirement to change the window from 0.5 to something else, you can use this logic (Note: @number is your input)

```
DECLARE @Number AS DECIMAL
SET @Number = 0.49

SELECT @Number+ CASE WHEN @Number%1 BETWEEN 0.000 AND 0.249 THEN 0.000 - @Number%1
                     WHEN @Number%1 BETWEEN 0.250 AND 0.500 THEN 0.500 -@Number%1
                     WHEN @Number%1 BETWEEN 0.500 AND 0.749 THEN 0.500 -@Number%1
                     WHEN @Number%1 BETWEEN 0.750 AND 0.999 THEN 1.000 -@Number%1
                END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cast

Select cast(YourX+0.5 as int);

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`SELECT CAST(ROUND(CAST(0.5 AS NUMERIC(5, 2)),0) AS int)`